# Yii 2 Getting unknown property: yii\web\View::attribute

Tags: php, yii, widget, yii2

I have a widget UploadmaWidget :

```
namespace vendor\maydin;
use yii\base\Widget;
use yii\helpers\Html;
class UploadmaWidget extends Widget
{
    public $message;
    public $model;
    public $attribute;
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        if ($this->message === null) {
            $this->message = 'Hello World';
        }
    }
    public function run()
    {
        UploadmaWidgetAsset::register($this->getView());
        return $this->render('index',['message'=>$this->message]);
    }
    public function getViewPath()
    {
        return '@vendor/maydin/views/';
    }

}
```

And I render in index view file:

```
 <?php
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\web\View;
    ?>
    <?= $this->message;?>
    <?= $this->attribute;?>
```

If I  call message value no problem but attribute is problem.I don't want to send attribute value via render function.

**EDIT**:Because I have such used widget in Yii 1.1 but it is not working in Yii 2.0 (NOW)

Finally I call widget like this:

```
<?php  
use vendor\maydin\UploadmaWidget;
echo UploadmaWidget::widget([
'message' => 'Hello World',
'model'=>$model,
'attribute' => 'mahmut', 
]) ;?>
```

How can I use attribute value in widget view file?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass attribute to View into `run` method of your `UploadmaWidget`, similar to passing message:

```
public function run()
{
    UploadmaWidgetAsset::register($this->getView());
    return $this->render('index',
        ['message'=>$this->message, 'attribute'=>$this->attribute]);
}
```

After this changes you can use `$this->attribute` into your view.

In Yii1 CWidget extends CBaseController and in view you can access CWidget public properties, but not in Yii2. We can compare realization here:

- Widget class in Yii2 and its [render](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/3f4fcbe569e3460ad7b28085b957c3b2f47b5334/framework/base/Widget.php#L185) method
- Widget class in Yii1 and its [render](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/485c001e99ba1e60eabd496027e69eecdee5ed72/framework/web/widgets/CWidget.php#L235) method

Comment: I have declare " I don't want to send attribute value via render function"

Comment: See how it works on github: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/3f4fcbe569e3460ad7b28085b957c3b2f47b5334/framework/base/Widget.php#L185. second attribut is `$params the parameters (name-value pairs) that should be made available in the view.`

Comment: If you don't want to send this attribute via render function then you do not want this attribute to be accessible in view

Comment: Why then question title is `Yii 2 Getting unknown property`?

Comment: I have used in Yii 1.1 but it is not working in Yii 2.0(NOW)

Comment: Here https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/485c001e99ba1e60eabd496027e69eecdee5ed72/framework/web/widgets/CWidget.php#L235 the same comment for render method signature in Yii1

Comment: Oh, I catch your question ... In Yii1 CWidget extends CBaseController and in view you can access CWidget public properties, but not in Yii2